# Dry Ice shipping with Fedex Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, fedex

Does anyone have any idea about shipping Dry Ice with FedEx in Magento 2. How to configure it in Magento 2 application

Answer (score 1):

Before configuring, read about [shipping dry ice with FedEx](http://www.fedex.com/downloads/jp_english/packagingtips/dryice_jobaid.pdf).

Default Magento 2 application does not support FedEx dry shipping. Instead, for [FedEx shipping with Magento](https://www.storepep.com/fedex-shipping-with-magento-using-storepep/), you can use StorePep. You just need to mark the product as Dry ice within StorePep. Using this information StorePep will automatically show Dry ice rates and also print a FedEx shipping label.